# android what is the different between InputMethodService.onKey and OnKeyboardActionListener.onkeydown

Tags: android, ime

what is the different between InputMethodService.onKey and OnKeyboardActionListener.onkeydown

which method i need to use if i want to handle the handleCharacter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnKeyboardActionListener.onkey` and `InputMethodService.onKeyDown` I think.

Basically, you should use `OnKeyboardActionListener.onkey`, its designed as a key event listener, you should implement and override it.

Answer (score 5):

**InputMethodService** provides a standard implementation of an InputMethod,Its help to inputdata Keyboard,user to draw text.*OnKeyboardActionListener.onkeydown* is used when u use the virtual keyboard in the device its gives the action on what is touched on the keyboard at that time.Similarly u can use *onkeyup* after the action is over.Handler are diffrent [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the onKeyDown is the hardkey listener and the onkey is the listener of the keyboard

you made.